# Unable to Read Blob Storage account Directories and sub Directories

Tags: blob, azure-blob-storage, blobstore, blobstorage

I am trying to read directories and sub directories of the storage account and unable to read, below is the sample code and attached blob container structure snapshot

sample code:

```
  CloudBlobContainer container = Retrier<CloudBlobContainer>.TryWithDelayIncremental(() => blobclient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName), NoOfRetries, DelayInMilliSecs);

var directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(@"policies /Initiatives");
            var folders = directory.ListBlobs().Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();
            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(folder.Uri);
            }
```

folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

container and folder:

[image: container and folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your capture, `policies` is the name of your container, if you want to get all URIs of folders under /Initiatives in container `policies`, you should not involve container name in directory reference name, try the code below :

```
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("policies");

    var directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(@"Initiatives");
    var folders = directory.ListBlobs().Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();
    foreach (var folder in folders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(folder.Uri);
    }
```

Test result on my side :
[image]
[image]